# Regarding the sequence of steps for the struts 2 workflow

Tags: struts2

I am a new bie to struts 2 although I am reading the and understood the flow of Struts 2 partially by reading mkyong tutorials for struts 2 , But please can some in sequence steps tell me the flow of struts 2 framework in detail.

Answer (score 1):

The flow sequence in struts can actually be found on the cover of Ian Roughley's book, Starting Struts2: http://www.infoq.com/minibooks/starting-struts2

[image]

I recommend it as an introduction to Struts2. I also recommend David Newton's Apache Struts 2.

Comment: @StevenBenitez Biggest issue with S2iA is that it's for S2.0, although all the XML stuff is still valid. There was a MEAP for an S2.1 recipes book that got ixnayed :( Thanks Oscar :)